# How to make the backword when some loss come from the eigenvector in PyTorch?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, linear-algebra, eigenvector

my loss seems like

```
e1, v1 = torch.eig(A)
e2, v2 = torch.eig(B)
sim = torch.matmul(v1, v2.permute(0, 2, 1))
loss_sim = torch.sum(sim)
loss_sim.backward()
```

where `A` and `B` is the intermediate tensors with shape `SEQUENCE_LENGH * SEQUENCE_LENGTH`

and my code meet the error:

`File "/usr/local/Anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/tensor.py", line 185, in backward  torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph) File "/usr/local/Anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py", line 125, in backward Variable._execution_engine.run_backward( RuntimeError: eig_backward: Backward calculation does not support complex eigenvalues at the moment. Exception raised from eig_backward at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1595629395347/work/torch/csrc/autograd/generated/Functions.cpp:1877 (most recent call first): frame #0: c10::Error::Error(c10::SourceLocation, std::string) + 0x4d (0x7f74932e077d in /usr/local/Anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libc10.so) frame #1: torch::autograd::generated::EigBackward::apply(std::vector<at::Tensor, std::allocator<at::Tensor> >&&) + 0xb5d (0x7f74cc4b894d in /usr/local/Anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so) frame #2: <unknown function> + 0x30d1017 (0x7f74ccb0c017 in /usr/local/Anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so) frame #3: torch::autograd::Engine::evaluate_function(std::shared_ptr<torch::autograd::GraphTask>&, torch::autograd::Node*, torch::autograd::InputBuffer&, std::shared_ptr<torch::autograd::ReadyQueue> const&) + 0x1400 (0x7f74ccb07860 in /usr/local/Anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so) frame #4: torch::autograd::Engine::thread_main(std::shared_ptr<torch::autograd::GraphTask> const&) + 0x451 (0x7f74ccb08401 in /usr/local/Anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so) frame #5: torch::autograd::Engine::thread_init(int, std::shared_ptr<torch::autograd::ReadyQueue> const&, bool) + 0x89 (0x7f74ccb00579 in /usr/local/Anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so) frame #6: torch::autograd::python::PythonEngine::thread_init(int, std::shared_ptr<torch::autograd::ReadyQueue> const&, bool) + 0x4a (0x7f74d0e2a1ba in /usr/local/Anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_python.so) frame #7: <unknown function> + 0xc819d (0x7f74d393719d in /usr/local/Anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/../../../.././libstdc++.so.6) frame #8: <unknown function> + 0x76ba (0x7f74ed28c6ba in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0) frame #9: clone + 0x6d (0x7f74ecfc241d in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6)`

How do I accomplish the backword with torch.eig()?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems with this example.

1. The backward of `torch.eig` is just implemented for matrices that have real eigenvalues [as per the documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.9.0/generated/torch.eig.html?highlight=eig#torch.eig)
2. This loss is not well-defined. As described in the documentation of `torch.linalg.eig`, [the eigenvalues are not uniquely defined](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.9.0/generated/torch.linalg.eig.html#torch.linalg.eig). As such, this loss is not well-defined, and neither are its gradients.

The first problem is easy to solve: Simply use `torch.linalg.eig`, which returns the complex eigenvalues of the matrix. For the second problem, you'll need to think a bit more about your model and whether you really want to use the eigenvalue decomposition. Please have a look at the `torch.linalg` documentation, as it provides some useful comments on the relation of this function with others which might be useful for you.